# How about new format Bundle app on Google play?

Tags: android, bundle

I am a newbie in developing Android. I've uploaded a signed bundle app completely. Then, I test it via downloading a configuration as an attached file.

1. Will the user download a zip file which contains 3 apk files? (2 config apks and base.apk).

> This makes a bit of difficulty for users who don't have knowledge about technology.

2. Can the user download one apk file (which is split from Bundle) like formatting apk in the past?

> [This is helpful in supporting more users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhJjk.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. No
2. Yes

Your app’s APK gets generated dynamically for each user when they install it from the Google Play Store according to the user’s device configuration. That way, they only download the resources and code for your app that they need. Hence, resulting in a smaller app size!

Comment: Thanks, also please see my comment to @jsRook below. :)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer

> Will the user download a zip file which contains 3 apk files? (2 config apks and base.apk).

Nope, the user will download only one app depending on the CPU of their Android phone

> Can user download one apk file (which is split from Bundle) like formatting apk in the past

Something similar like this, but this is handled by the play store itself

First You need to know about bundle [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52550332/10304059)

Google Play’s new app serving model, called Dynamic Delivery, then uses your app bundle to generate and serve optimized APKs for each user’s device configuration, so they download only the code and resources they need to run your app. You no longer have to build, sign, and manage multiple APKs to support different devices, and users get smaller, more optimized downloads.

Comment: Hi, I follow steps as below to get apk for my device:                                                 1. Go to App bundle explorer.                                                                                               2. Next, go to Download device-specific APKs, choose device and download.             The result, I downloaded one file and requested to extract and get 3 apk files: config.xxhdpi.apk, config.en.apk and base.apk(this is my app after installed.).         You can explain for me about that?

Comment: Hi, Anyone can explain for me about that? The steps above to test apk one device. So, when app is release, user will also download one zip file or only one apk ?